# got "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?", but docker is running now

Tags: docker

I tried to use `sudo docker images`, `docker images`, restart docker by docker desktop, restart docker desktop app, reinstall docker by deleting docker.app from applications and then reinstall by `brew install --cask docker`.

**What I saw:**
docker desktop show `Docker Desktop is running`. but still cannot use docker command in terminal.

the first version of docker.app moved from old mac (using Migration Assistant app).

MacOS: 13.2.1 with M2

UPDATE:

```
$ > ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  40  4 30 16:49 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/afraidjpg/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

socket file is exist! but, it seems like a symbol link to `/Users/afraidjpg/...`, and my username is `afraid_jpg` so I got the error:

```
$ > ls -l  /Users/afraidjpg/.docker/run/docker.sock
ls: /Users/afraidjpg/.docker/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory
```

How to configure the path of `docker.sock`?

user of Docker.app:

```
ls -l /Applications | grep Docker
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 afraid_jpg  staff  96  4 27 04:32 Docker.app
```

Comment: and is there a socket at /var/run/docker.sock?  If there isn't, it won't work; if there is, something else is happening.

Comment: In the error message you quote the normal plain-Docker Linux socket path, but if you're using Docker Desktop then the path will be different (somewhere in your home directory), and you will get very different behavior with and without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix this by create a new symbol link to correct path with:
`ln -s -f /var/run/docker.sock /Users/afraid_jpg/.docker/run/docker.sock`.
then restart the docker and it works